# Code contracts static checker: Possibly calling a method on a null reference — why?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have the following class:

```
public class AndSpecification<TEntity> : ISpecification<TEntity>
{
    protected ISpecification<TEntity> First { get; private set; }
    protected ISpecification<TEntity> Second { get; private set; }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity entity)
    {
        return First.IsSatisfiedBy(entity) && Second.IsSatisfiedBy(entity);
    }

    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<TEntity> first, ISpecification<TEntity> second)
    {
        Contract.Requires(first != null);
        Contract.Requires(second != null);
        Contract.Ensures(First != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Second != null);

        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}
```

Note that I use `Contract.Ensures()` to ensure that after the constructor is invoked, `First` and `Second` are never null. However, Code Contracts give me a warning in `IsSatisfiedBy()` method implementation: `CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'this.First'` (same for the `Second`). Can't figure out what's wrong, is that me or the static checker?

Comment: Does making that field read only make a difference?

Comment: You might want to add a class invariant that states that the properties are never null.

Comment: I think Contract.Ensures only ensures that the properties First and Second are not null after constructor call and not in the method IsSatisfiedBy. Using an Invariant seems to be the way

Comment: @PeterRitchie no, adding `readonly` backing fields does not help.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever @Jehof that helped, thanks! I thought that CodeContracts should infer the fact that `First` and `Second` can't be `null` in the `IsSatisfiedBy()` method because I set them in the constructor only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are missing some contracts and object invariants. I took your code above and ran Code Contracts static analysis on it and got exactly what you got. Then I worked my way through the code to arrive at an implementation that satisfies the static analyzer.

```
[ContractClass(typeof(ISpecificationContracts<>))]
public interface ISpecification<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity entity);
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(ISpecification<>))]
abstract class ISpecificationContracts<TEntity> 
    : ISpecification<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity entity)
    {
        Contract.Requires(entity != null);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AndSpecification<TEntity> 
    : ISpecification<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly ISpecification<TEntity> _first;
    private readonly ISpecification<TEntity> _second;

    protected ISpecification<TEntity> First {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ISpecification<TEntity>>() != null);
            return _first;
        }
    }
    protected ISpecification<TEntity> Second
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ISpecification<TEntity>>() != null);
            return _second;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity entity)
    {
        return First.IsSatisfiedBy(entity) && Second.IsSatisfiedBy(entity);
    }

    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<TEntity> first,
                            ISpecification<TEntity> second)
    {
        Contract.Requires(first != null);
        Contract.Requires(second != null);
        Contract.Ensures(_first == first);
        Contract.Ensures(_second == second);

        _first = first;
        _second = second;
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
        "Microsoft.Performance", 
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic", 
        Justification = "Required for code contracts.")]
    private void ObjectInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_first != null);
        Contract.Invariant(_second != null);
    }

}
```